# C++: Pointer value changed exiting a function

Tags: c++, c, pointers

I need to wrap a string vector from an unmanaged C++ library, and to do so I have to convert a `vector<string>` to a `char***`. For this conversion, I'm using a function. However, even if it seems right inside it, once out pointer values changed to be invalid.

Here is a simple example of it:

```
int main() {
    cout << "Start of the program" << endl;

    vector<string> vStr = vector<string>();
    vStr.push_back("ABC");
    vStr.push_back("DEF");
    vStr.push_back("GHI");
    vStr.push_back("JKL");
    vStr.push_back("MNO");
    vStr.push_back("PQR");

    char*** pStr = new char**();
    int* pLength = new int();

    cout << " > before export" << endl;

    exportVector(vStr, pStr, pLength);

    cout << " < after export" << endl;

    cout << "\t pLength value = " << *pLength << endl;

    for (unsigned int i = 0 ; i < vStr.size(); i++)
    {
        cout <<"\t pStr "<< i << ": " << vStr[i] << " to ";
        for(unsigned int j = 0; j < 3; ++j)
        {
            cout << "-" << pStr[0][i][j];
        }
        cout << "-"<< endl;
    }

    cout << "End of the program" << endl;

    delete pStr;
    delete pLength;

    return 0;
}

void exportVector(vector<string> vect, char*** pData, int* pSize)
{
    vector<char*> charVect = vector<char*>(vect.size());
    //cout << "\t charVect.size() = " << charVect.size() << endl;

    // Copy and cast elements of given vector into chars
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < vect.size() ; i++)
    {
        charVect[i] = const_cast<char*>(vect[i].c_str());
    }

    *pData = &charVect[0];
    *pSize = vect.size();

    cout << "\t pSize = " << *pSize << endl;
    for (unsigned int i = 0 ; i < vect.size(); i++)
    {
        cout <<"\t pData "<< i << ": ";
        for(unsigned int j = 0 ; j < 3 ; ++j)
        {
            cout << "-" << pData[0][i][j];
        }
        cout << "-"<< endl;
    }
}
```

And I'm getting in console:

```
Start of the program
 > before export
     pSize = 6
     pData 0: -A-B-C-
     pData 1: -D-E-F-
     pData 2: -G-H-I-
     pData 3: -J-K-L-
     pData 4: -M-N-O-
     pData 5: -P-Q-R-
 < after export
     pLength value = 6
     pStr 0: ABC to -Ä- -i-
     pStr 1: DEF to - - -i-
     pStr 2: GHI to -G-H-I-
     pStr 3: JKL to -J-K-L-
     pStr 4: MNO to -M-N-O-
     pStr 5: PQR to -P-Q-R-
End of the program
```

How to explain the difference of values inside `exportVector` function and outside it? How to correct it?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Just because you need to use those ugly triple pointers, that is no reason to make the rest of the code bad. Keep using `vector`, drop the `new` nonsense.

Comment: To point out one thing among many: You do realize you can just declare an `int` to replace `pLength` and pass it by address to `exportVector`, right?

Comment: Thanks for your answers. Unfortunately, as I said, I need this triple pointer for marshalling... Yes, I know that I could have use another way for pLength.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass your vector by reference

```
void exportVector(vector<string> &vect, char*** pData, int* pSize)
```

,also you should use strdup here:

```
charVect[i] = const_cast<char*>(vect[i].c_str());
//should be
charVect[i] = strdup(vect[i].c_str());
```

finally,

```
vector<char*> charVect = vector<char*>(vect.size());
*pData = &charVect[0];
```

will segfault cause charVect will be destroyed at the end of the function,
you need to remove those line and do something like this:

```
(*pData) = new char*[vect.size()];
// Copy and cast elements of given vector into chars
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < vect.size() ; i++)
{
    (*pData)[i] = strdup(vect[i].c_str());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Indeed, I could use another way for pLength. However it is not explaining the problem with pStr.

Comment: You need to pass vect by reference because if not it's being copied in the stack and so at the end of exportVector function it get destroyed with its data

Comment: Isn't it charVect that should stay consistent? In this case, a reference on vect would not help...

Comment: so use strdup to copy your strings, cause you have pointers referring to strings in the vector, if you copy them you won't be dependant from the vector anymore

Comment: I have tried your propositions: passing vector by reference, using strdup (even strcpy) without any change in my results... :/

Comment: Ok, I compiled it myself, and you doing the same mistake at the beginning of exportVector, vector<char*> charVect = vector<char*>(vect.size()); will be destroyed at the end of the function, so you need to to something like this:
(*pData) = new char*[vect.size()]; instead of the above line and comment out *pData = charVect;, it work for me

Comment: I edited the answers, but you should tweak it in a more c++ way

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's been really helpful.
Another way to do it: [link](http://www.developpez.net/forums/d1393220/c-cpp/cpp/passage-adresse-d-triple-pointeur/)

Comment: Haha, devellopez plus rapide sur ce coup la !

Answer (score 1):

You are passing the vector by value to the exportVector function! The vector gets destructed after the function returns, and your char* pointers get orphaned, pointing to memory locations which probably are reused for other purposes afterwards...

Also, your `const_cast` should ring a lot of alarm bells already! Never do a `const_cast` (except for very rare occasions where you know it is safe to do so - and this is not one of them)!

But those things are not the only problems in your code. What do you think `char*** pStr = new char**();` is doing?
What it does is that it reserves space for one pointer to a pointer to a char (usually 4-8 byte). You seem to think that somehow magically allocates space for a multitude of character arrays?

Comment: OK. But how can we make it consistent?